# How to fetch data from same column using different criteria?

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqlanywhere

Hi I have table like this in SQL anywhere database

```
CUSTID-------DDAT.----------AMOUNT
1.         01-01-2021.       1000
1.         02-02-2021.       2000
1.         03-02-2021.       3000
1.         04-02-2021.       4000
2.         01-04-2021.        1000
2.         02-04-2021.         2000
```

2. ```
            04-04-2021.         1000
   ```

I want data like this in VB.net  where amount is only for one date and total amount is for 4 day

```
Cust id.------date ---------------Amount.-------Total amount
1.             04-04-2021.          4000.                 10000
 2.             04-04-2021.          1000.                 4000
```

Can you give me any solution..thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know which date you want?  Why doesn't the first column match the second?

Comment: *"I tried many SQL queries"*. If we can't see it then it didn't happen. Show us the one attempt that you think should work. That's how this site works. It's not *"I want to do X, show me how"*. It's *"I want to do X, this is how I'm trying, tell me how to fix it"*.

Answer (score 0):

My take on it:

```
select custid, dat, amount, total_amount
from (
    select custid, dat, amount, sum(amount) over (partition by custid) as total_amount
    from data
) d
where dat = '2021-04-04' -- or any other date
```

Might be that the inner select is all that you need. Not sure if the filter on date is necessary.